# How can get result of sql for this table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `temp_user_notes` that is the temporary table of user table and notes table

Its structure is

```
id  user_id note_id  current_version  old_version  updated_date note_date
1    2                    4             3          2016-17-12
2    3                    4             3          2016-17-12
3    4                    4             4          
4    2        40                                                2016-18-12
5    3        45                                                2016-18-12
6    4        41                                                2016-18-12
```

I have two type of users, one with `current_version = old_version` and second `current_version != old_version`. I am trying to get `note_id` of those second users but only those notes which are created after updated date.

Also, all notes of first type users who dont have updated date.

```
SELECT * FROM temp_user_notes 
WHERE user_id IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
    FROM temp_user_notes 
    WHERE current_version = old_version);

SELECT DISTINCT user_id, version_number_updated_at FROM temp_user_notes
WHERE current_version != previous_version
GROUP BY user_id, version_number_updated_at;
```

I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you'll need to add a field to your table that keeps track of when it was added using the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP property, say it's called create_date. Your query should look something like:

```
SELECT node_id FROM temp_user_notes WHERE current_version != old_version AND updated_date < create_date
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a max of 2 entries per user_id.

```
/*
DROP TABLE TEMP;
CREATE TABLE TEMP (ID INT,USER_ID INT, NOTE_ID INT,CURRENT_VERSION INT,OLD_VERSION INT,UPDATE_DATE DATE,NOTE_DATE DATE);
TRUNCATE TABLE TEMP;
INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES
(1 ,   2 ,     NULL,               4 ,            3,          '2016-12-17'    ,         NULL),
(2 ,   3 ,     NULL,               4 ,            3,          '2016-12-17'    ,         NULL ),
(3 ,   4 ,     NULL,               4 ,            4,          NULL,                    NULL),
(4 ,   2 ,       40,            NULL,         NULL ,          NULL ,               '2016-12-18'),
(5 ,   3 ,       45,            NULL,          NULL,          NULL  ,              '2016-12-18'),
(6 ,   4 ,       41,            NULL,          NULL,          NULL   ,             '2016-12-18');
*/


SELECT T1.USER_ID,T2.NOTE_ID
        #T1.* ,T2.*
FROM    TEMP T1
INNER   JOIN    TEMP T2 ON T2.USER_ID = T1.USER_ID
WHERE   T2.ID > T1.ID
        AND T1.CURRENT_VERSION <> T1.OLD_VERSION
        AND T2.NOTE_DATE > T1.UPDATE_DATE
```